# allocating data structures while making the borrow checker happy

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm writing my first rust program and as expected I'm having problems making the borrow checker happy. Here is what I'm trying to do:

I would like to have a function that allocates some array, stores the array in some global data structure, and returns a reference to it. Example:

```
static mut global_data = ...

fn f() -> &str {
  let s = String::new();
  global.my_string = s;
  return &s;
};
```

Is there any way to make something like this work? If not, what is "the rust way"(tm) to get an array and a pointer into it?

Alternatively, is there any documentation I could read? The rust book is unfortunately very superficial on most topics.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple things wrong with your code:

1. Using global state is very unidiomatic in rust. It *can* be done in some specific scenarios, but it should never be a go to method. You cold try wrapping your state in `Rc` or `Arc` and share it this way in your program. If you also want to mutate this state (as you show in your example) you must to wrap it also in some kind of interior mutability type. So try `Rc<RefCell<State>>` if you want to use state in only one thread or `Arc<Mutex<State>>` if you want to use it from multiple different threads.
2. Accessing mutable static memory is *unsafe*. So even the following code won't compile:

```rust
static mut x: i32 = 0;

// neither of this lines work!
println!("{}", x);
x = 42;
```

You must use `unsafe` to access or modify any static mutable variables, because you must de facto prove to the compiler that you assure it that no data races (from accessing this data from different threads) will occur.

3. I can't be sure, since you didn't show what type is `global_data`, but I assume, that `my_string` is a field of type `String`. When you write

```rust
let s = String::new();
global.my_string = s;
```

You *move* ownership of that string to the `global`. You therefore cannot return (or even create) reference to it. You must do this though it's new owner. `&global.my_string` *could* work, but not if you do what I written in 1. You could try to return `RefMut` of `MutexGuard`, but that is probably not what you want.

Comment: Thanks, but that does not address my problem. Let's simplify my example to better see what I mean. Instead of storing s in a global variable, let's say I just want to return both s and &s. I.e. in my example above delete the variable global completely and replace the return statement by return (s, &s); That still does not compile.

Comment: @Achim that is impossible for a different reason. Consider that `&s` is a reference, which must point at the location of `s`, and that you are moving `s` (and `&s` with it), where will `&s` be pointing?

Comment: @ZoeyHewll Maybe I'm completely misunderstanding how rust works. But as far as I understand s consists of a struct pointing to an array of u8 and if I move s, I only move the struct, not the array. But &s is a pointer to the array, so it shouldn't change. Or is this wrong?

Comment: @Achim `&s` is a pointer to `s` itself, if you want a pointer to the array of characters, you need `&s[..]` or `s.as_str()`

Comment: That is true. I apologise. A pointer or reference to the String (struct) will have the problem that I described above, but a pointer to the string's backing storage will not. But even @Jmb's solution has an issue. I'll try to explain

Comment: A reference promises that it points to valid data, and the string is in charge of when it deallocates or reallocates its data. If you return the string and someone drops it, or pushes too much data to it so that it needs to allocate larger storage, then the reference (to the string's array of u8's) will point to invalid data (classic Use-After-Free).

Comment: @Jmb Thanks. But even if I change `&s` to `&s[..]` the code does not compile.

Comment: Rust's borrow rules exist (in part) to prevent Use-After-Free. In this case, the rules have to guarantee that the string will never deallocate while the reference is alive, which means preventing anyone from moving ownership of the string (as the new owner may drop it, causing it to free the storage) or mutably accessing the string (as mutable access may cause the string to reallocate to new storage)

Comment: @Zoey Thanks. Is there some way to persuade rust that 'I know what I'm doing and won't invalidate the reference'? Of course, the `String` example above was just a condensed version of what I'm actually trying to do. I would like to allocate a data structure and an iterator over that structure at the same time and return both from a function. Is there some way to do that in rust?

Comment: The "it's OK compiler, I now what I'm doing" button is called `unsafe`, but I want to second @Sedat Kapanoglu and say, we might be able to help you to avoid using `unsafe` if we know why you need to do this, e.g. to know what structure you're implementing. In a lot of cases, rust has existing safe abstractions for common unsafe patterns.

Comment: @Zoey I of course tried adding `unsafe`, but the code still does not compile. So you are saying there is no way to write such code in rust? (I don't want to use the existing data structures from the standard library, I'd rather learn how implement such things myself.)

Comment: One way to make my code safe would be if I could specify that 'I return a tuple `(String, &str)` where the lifetime of the second component is that of the first component.' But I suppose the type system of rust is not strong enough to do this.

Comment: Ah, apologies, I forgot to explain further, and my answer was a little bit dismissive and perhaps misleading. The answer is not quite "use `unsafe`" but "use raw pointers", with the caveat that in order for anyone to access what is behind a pointer, they must use `unsafe`. I would recommend reading the [Rust Book's chapter on Unsafe Rust](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-01-unsafe-rust.html) to get an idea of what `unsafe` is for.

Comment: @Zoey Thanks a lot. Using a pointer instead of a reference works.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, just in case someone else is having the same question, the following code seems to work:

```
struct foo {
  b : Option<Box<u32>>,
}

static mut global : foo = foo { b : None };

fn f<'a>() -> &'a u32 {
  let b : Box<u32> = Box::new(5);

  unsafe {
    global.b = Some(b);

    match &global.b {
      None    => panic!(""),
      Some(a) => return &a,
    }
  }
}
```

At least it compiles. Hopefully it will also do the right thing when run.

I'm aware that this is not how you are supposed to do things in rust. But I'm currently trying to figure out how to implement various data structures from scratch, and the above is just a reduced example of one of the problems I encountered.

Comment: When Rust compiles safe code, it's pretty much a guarantee that it won't have memory related bugs. `unsafe` code on the other hand, doesn't have such guarantees. Why would you risk that? I'd gladly change my design over trying to push this. Perhaps you can ask another question based on the actual data structure you're working on, and a better answer can be found?