# allocating data structures while making the borrow checker happy (second try)

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

As a follow up to my question from yesterday ([allocating data structures while making the borrow checker happy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74157639/allocating-data-structures-while-making-the-borrow-checker-happy)),
here is a simplified case. I would like to create a data structure and return both it and a reference to it. The following code does not compile:

```
fn create() -> (String, &str) {
  let s = String::new();
  let r = &s;
  return (s,r);
}

fn f() {
  let (s,r) = create();
  do_something(r);
}
```

If I restructure my code as follows, everything works fine:

```
fn create<'a>(s : &'a String) -> &'a str {
  let r = &s;
  return r;
}

fn f() {
  let s = String::new();
  let r = create(&s);
  do_something(r);
}
```

Unfortunately, in some cases structuring the code as in the first example is much preferable. Is there some way to make rust accept the first version?

Since both versions of the code do exactly the same thing, there shouldn't be any problems with safety. The question is just whether rust's type system is powerful enough to express it.

Answer (score 1):

The Rust rules on references are that an object can either have

- any amount of immutable references,
- *or* exactly one mutable reference.

In other words, you cannot have an immutable reference and a mutable reference to the same object at the same time. Since the object counts as a mutable reference to itself, you cannot modify the object while an immutable reference to the object is present.

This is why your first piece of code does not compile. When you return `(String, &str)`, `String` contains a mutable reference to a byte array, and `&str` contains an immutable reference to the same byte array. It violates the borrow checker rules.

However, you may ask, how does the second piece of code work? It works because you never attempt to modify `s`. If you modify `s` *after* `r` is created, then it will fail to compile:

```rust
fn f() {
    let mut s = String::new();
    let r = &s;
    s += "modified"; // ERROR: cannot borrow `s` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
    do_something(r); 
}
```

You shouldn't need to return a data structure and a reference to itself. Simply invoke the reference when it is necessary, rather than storing it in a variable. This will make sure that the borrow checker doesn't complain about references colliding.

```rust
fn f() {
    let s = String::new();
    // If a function takes &str, passing &String will be implicitly converted to &str
    do_something(&s);
    s += "modified"; // Perfectly fine, will still compile
    do_something_else(&s);
}
```

If you want to learn more about why the `&String` => `&str` conversion works, see the [`std::convert::AsRef`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.AsRef.html) trait.

Comment: As far as I understand, a `String` is a struct containing a pointer to an array of `u8`. When I move the `String` only the struct gets copied while the array remains in place, doesn't it? The reference on the other hand points to the array, not the struct. So it shouldn't be affected by the move. Or is this wrong?

Comment: @Achim Good point, I realised my explanation was incorrect and I've edited it to the proper explanation.

Comment: @Achim The first explanation was correct, the second is... less so, although it is somewhat applicable too. The fact that `String` contains a pointer is not known to the borrow checker, and I think it is also right since `String` contains `Unique`. In other words, using a raw pointer is UB.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution: use a raw pointer instead of a reference. The following code works:

```
fn create() -> (String, *const u8) {
  let s = String::new();
  let r = s.as_ptr();
  return (s,r);
}

fn f() {
  let (s,r) = create();
  do_something(r);
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't do this - this is unsafe for the reasons stated in my (now edited) comment. Tip: In general, you should not need to use unsafe in Rust unless you explicitly know you need to violate the borrow checker rules. If you don't know the exact rule you're violating, why you're violating it, and which variables you're violating it for, then you probably don't need to use unsafe. If you can't get your creation past the borrow checker, that's usually a sign that you've structured your code wrong, and you should restructure your code.